# form.is_valid() no me funciona

Tags: python, django

Buenas estoy haciendo un proyecto de prueba y me ocurre lo siguiente.

Esto deberia devolverme un error siempre por el post, pero no lo hace, se salta el if y me redirecciona siempre para el success_url, y no tengo idea de porque.
Alguien que me ayude se lo agradeceria

```
class TomarOrdenView(BSModalUpdateView):

    
       model = Orden
       template_name = 'Orden/ModalTomarOrden.html'
       form_class = TomarDejarOrdenForm
       success_url = "/Oficina/"
      
       
       def post(self, request,pk ,*args, **kwargs):
          
          form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    
          if form.is_valid():
       
             if 1 == 1:
                form.add_error('profesional', 'error')
             
             return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
    
          return render(request, self.template_name,{'form':form})
```

Comment: No se  salta el `if`, sucede que si no pones un `return` dentro del `if`, el método seguirá su ejecución en la siguiente linea. Podrías usar una sentencia `else` para que metas esa redirección allí. Revisa tu lógica, porque la falla está allí. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias ya me funciona. El problema es que yo pensaba que al enviar el error con form.add_error('profesional', 'error') automaticamente salia de la condicion  if form.is_valid(): como False y me llamaba a esta linea return render(request, self.template_name,{'form':form}), pero bueno parece que estaba equivocado. Gracias